# Error with decorators es6 angular2 ionic2 typescript

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript2.0, angular2-decorators

i've got a bug with ionic2.

the context:

I make a empty project with `ionic start myProject --v2`.
I've import my entity {User} in about.ts and i make a new User() in code.

but User use a decorator "@myDeco."

the compilation send no error but ionic does:

Cannot resolve all parameters for `'Parser'(?)`. Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Parser' is decorated with Injectable.

or

Unexpected value 'HomePage' declared by the module 'AppModule'

if i comment @myDeco it's works well. (of course i've installed reflect-metadata with npm install)

tree:

```
src/bdd/entity/User.ts
src/bdd/reflect/myreflect.ts
src/pages/about/about.ts
```

code:

myreflect.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';    
    export function myDeco(target: any, key: string) : void{
    var t = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
    console.log(`${key} type: ${t.name}`);
}
```

User.ts

```
import {myDeco} from '../reflexif/myreflect'
export class User { 
    @myDeco
    private login: string;
    public setlogin(login: string) {this.login=login;}
}
```

About.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {User} from '../../bdd/entity/User'
@Component({
    selector: 'page-about',
    templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        let u = new User();
        u.setLogin('grgr');
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Michael.

Comment: Is not `@myDeco()` correct syntax for decorators in typescript?

Comment: the () is used if i've put parameter in decorator.
in my exemple i've no parameter...

Comment: I said BullShit... sorry. the () is for angular decorator. After reading many answer, i wish make a decorator with () and the probleme wish solved.
So i could try this. 
Bur one question.. how to creator decorator with () like @Input()